# Reaction of Grignard reagents with phosphoric acid derivatives

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reaction-control, grignard-reagent

The use of Grignard reagents that people are most familiar with is the production of tertiary alcohols by reaction with a suitable carbonyl compound, whether it be an ester, ketone, or aldehyde. As I understand it, Grignard reagents are strong nucleophiles and will readily attack any electrophilic centers. If so, how would a reagent having the formula RMgX react with a phosphoric acid derivative $\ce{(R^1)(R^2)(R^3)P=O}$, where $\ce{R^1}$, $\ce{R^2}$, and $\ce{R^3}$ can be either alkyl, alkoxy, $\ce{-OH}$, or $\ce{-H}$? Does it result in simply $\ce{(R3)P=O}$, a mixture of products where one or more of the $\ce{R}$ groups in the phosphoric acid derivative is replaced by that of the Grignard reagent, or something else? Is the result controlled by stoichiometry?

Answer (score 4):

According to this JOC paper by Hays,<sup>[1]</sup> diethyl phosphonate $\ce{(EtO)2P(O)H}$ has been reacted with alkyl or aryl Grignards to give secondary phosphines oxides and unsymmetrical tertiary phosphine oxides.

According to this JOC paper by Berlin and Peterson,<sup>[2]</sup> trimethyl phosphate $\ce{(MeO)3PO}$ has been reacted with phenyl Grignard to give methyl diphenylphosphinate $\ce{Ph2P(O)OMe}$ and triphenylphosphine oxide.

It is worthy of note that this patent<sup>[3]</sup> describes the use of triethyl phosphate $\ce{(EtO)3PO}$ as a solvent for the preparation of Grignard reagents.

#### References:

1. Hays, H. R. Reaction of diethyl phosphonate with methyl and ethyl Grignard reagents. *J. Org. Chem.* **1968,** *33* (10), 3690–3694. [DOI: 10.1021/jo01274a003](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01274a003).
2. Berlin, K. D.; Peterson, M. E. Nucleophilic displacement reaction on organophosphorus esters by Grignard reagents. II. Evidence for competitive displacement on carbon and phosphorus in the reaction of Grignard reagents with simple phosphates. *J. Org. Chem.* **1967,** *32* (1), 125–129. [DOI: 10.1021/jo01277a032](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo01277a032).
3. Matsui, M.; Kitahara, T.; Yabuta, G.; Yamada, T. Triethyl phosphate as the solvent for the preparation of Grignard reagents. *Proceedings of the Japan Academy. Ser. B: Physical and Biological Sciences* **1999,** *75* (2), 35–36. [DOI: 10.2183/pjab.75.35](https://doi.org/10.2183/pjab.75.35).